# SQL Server 2005 DBA Learning Resource

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, admin

So I have some experience with Microsoft Access, building database apps for people, vba, etc for different folks at work....different divisions. And I have actually learned a lot in that realm...however,

now the need for SQL Server has arrived, and I have never really ventured into that realm...so let the questions begin:

how vastly different is what i am about to get myself into?

i know that experience is the best teacher, but i actually learned a lot through books when it came to access, vba, sql, etc....so can anyone suggest materials/resources for learning like this??

seems as though I am going to have to learn to be the dba....so i gotta get crackin on the learning so i appreciate any and all help A LOT!! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft e-learning provides a few free courses and a free ebook targeting SQL Server 2008 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/training/sql-server.aspx) (not sure why you are targeting SQL Server 2005).

Of interest: [SQL Server 2005 Learning Resources](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/learning-resources.aspx)

Database design skills to some extent transcend the RDBMS; a big difference when moving from Access is the use of stored procedures and the T-SQL constructs available to you.

The [Microsoft Press books](http://blogs.msdn.com/microsoft_press/archive/2009/09/23/new-book-inside-microsoft-sql-server-2008-t-sql-programming.aspx) are excellent.

[SQL Server 2005 Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms130214(SQL.90).aspx) contains almost everything you need to know, but the structure is quite daunting at first.

One thing that is really worth learning is how to use is SQL Server Profiler, not just for profiling performance problems, but also for seeing what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: thanks I downloaded the SQL Server 2005 Books Online. Looks like I can learn a lot here. I appreciate the help, and will investigate all avenues!! 2005: because we (being my team) are taking over a 2005 SQL Server database at work, so i need to learn as much as possible about it. thanks mitch